# How can a Xamarin app send data to Desmos app?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm making a math app with xamarin.forms. I have an option called "show graph" and since I found it too hard to plot the graph using libraries, I want to use the app Desmos(very popular). So when the user presses "show graph", if Desmos is installed on the device, the app will open with the equation from my app. So the steps would be:

[in my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NJmF.png)

to this:

[in Desmos app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rg8t4.png)

How would this be possible using c# and Xamarin?You can open other apps easily with Xamarin.Essentials, but how would I actually make a change inside that opened app?

Comment: do you have any reason to expect that `Desmos` accepts data from external sources?

Comment: They support a javascript interface, so you can use their server or self-host it. You can use their servers by applying for an API key. https://www.desmos.com/api/v1.7/docs/index.html

Comment: How does "use their server" help with "using their app"? IMHO, this isn't a xamarin question. Its a question to ask the maintainers of Desmos. Unless you have a link to a doc from them, that says how to send data to **their app**. The time to ask a question on StackOverflow, is once you have information that says how to access app, have attempted to write code to implement that, and get stuck. I've changed title to the specific situation.

Comment: This depends on the Desmos app has a such interface or not. If the app has a such interface which accepts the data and show the graph, you can call it directly. If there is no such a interface, you can't do that.